# React did not render component on Ant.Design Layout content

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I am using the Ant.design UI framework for my apps. I have some problems regarding navigating by using Layout.sider. Whenever i click on the menu item it does change the URL but the component does not render.

[image: Example of UI]

**This is my code**

**Home.jsx**

```
  const { Header, Sider } = Layout;
  return (
    <>
      <Header className="inheritBg margin-bottom">
        <Topbar currentURL={currentURL} />
      </Header>
      <Layout className="inheritBg">
        <Router>
          <Sider>
            <Sidebar/> // This is my sidebar that i have created, see below for the code
          </Sider>
          <Content /> // This is my content that i created by myself, see below for the code
        </Router>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Content.jsx**

```
      <Layout.Content>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DesignDocumentations} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Layout.Content>
```

**Sidebar.jsx**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Menu
          theme="dark"
          mode="inline"
          onOpenChange={this.onOpenChange}
          openKeys={this.state.openKeys}
        >
          {dummy.map(m => {
            return (
              <SubMenu
                key={m.id}
                onTitleClick={this.props.openSubmenu.bind(null, m.name)}
                title={<span>{m.name}</span>}
              >
                {m.submodule.map(e => {
                  return (
                    <Menu.Item
                      key={e.id}
                      onClick={this.props.openItem.bind(null, this)}
                    >
                      <NavLink to="/dashboard">
                        <span>{e.module}</span>
                      </NavLink>
                    </Menu.Item>
                  );
                })}
              </SubMenu>
            );
          })}
        </Menu>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

All the code is still hardcoded and as i am new to react and still figuring the way that i can change the content when click the menu item. Anyone can help me what wrong on my code? I would appreciate that and thank you guys

Comment: Kindly provide your `this.props.openItem` function as well. The function that you are using to navigate. Along with the `BrowserHistory` you are navigating through

Comment: currently, the `props.openItem` is useless because before this i did not implement the router and only use the `props.openItem` to render something. But now i need to use the routing to render component.

Comment: I added new code in my question, check it out. Maybe it have something wrong with it.

Comment: Is `NavLink` imported from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Yes sir @HussainNawazLalee . I use it to control the navigation. Already tried using `NavLink` and `Link`

Comment: Remove the `Router` component from both the `Home.jsx` and `Content.jsx`. You only need to wrap your app inside a Router once

Comment: omg, its working now. Thank you sir :thumbsup for you